# type error in nuxt js 3 middleware : Cannot find name 'defineNuxtRouteMiddleware'.ts(2304)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have started new project with Nuxt 3 ,

this is Package.json

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.0.3",
    "daisyui": "^2.6.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.0.0-rc.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/vue": "^2.0.11",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.2",
    "@vueform/multiselect": "^2.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "jenesius-vue-modal": "^1.7.2",
    "vee-validate": "^4.6.7",
    "vue-recaptcha-v3": "^2.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  }
}
```

and I have middleware like this

**middlesware/auth.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    if (to.params.id === '1') {
      return abortNavigation()
    }
    return navigateTo('/')
  })
```

But I get this Typescript error

```
Cannot find name 'defineNuxtRouteMiddleware'.ts(2304)
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you provide reproduction? Your dependencies don't even include `typescript`. When/where does the error appear? You don't have to import/define `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware`. `middleSware` is probably a typo.

Comment: @some-user what do you mean by reproduction ?

Comment: Code and all necessary steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75941108/cannot-find-name-definenuxtconfig-ts2304