# Cannot find name 'defineNuxtConfig'.ts(2304)

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I tried to install Nuxt 3 layers inside a monorepo with turborepo. and I somehow get error with typescript where it's seems to not able to figure out nuxt

[defineNuxtConfig not find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fx6kB.png)

[appConfig not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye7sx.png)

the ts config file look like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./.playground/.nuxt/tsconfig.json"
}
```

and on .playground/.nuxt folder there's tsconfig that look like this(auto-generated):

```
// Generated by nuxi
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "..",
    "paths": {
      "~": [
        "."
      ],
      "~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@": [
        "."
      ],
      "@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "~~": [
        "."
      ],
      "~~/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "@@": [
        "."
      ],
      "@@/*": [
        "./*"
      ],
      "assets": [
        "assets"
      ],
      "public": [
        "public"
      ],
      "#app": [
        "../../../node_modules/nuxt/dist/app"
      ],
      "#app/*": [
        "../../../node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/*"
      ],
      "vue-demi": [
        "../../../node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/compat/vue-demi"
      ],
      "@vueuse/head": [
        "../../../node_modules/@unhead/vue/dist/index"
      ],
      "#imports": [
        ".nuxt/imports"
      ],
      "#build": [
        ".nuxt"
      ],
      "#build/*": [
        ".nuxt/*"
      ],
      "#components": [
        ".nuxt/components"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "./nuxt.d.ts",
    "../**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "../dist",
    "../.output"
  ]
}
```

how can i fix this so that defineNuxtConfig is recognized properly?

remove error Cannot find name 'defineNuxtConfig'.ts(2304)

Comment: Did u manage to solve the issue? It is impacting auto import on the whole layer which is very annoying to keep consistency across the monorepo

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same problem, weirdly enough after trying a few things what fixed it for me was changing the VSCode plugin Volar:Typescript Version to `Use workspace version` THEN changing back to `Use VS Code's Version`

[image]

How:

1. On VSCode press `F1` or `Ctrl + Shift + P`
2. Type `Volar: Select Typescript Version`
3. Select `Use workspace version`
4. Repeat steps 1 & 2
5. But this time select `Use VS Code's Version`

Bam, all my nuxt3 autoimports are correctly typed, don't know why tho.

Answer (score 8):

Not an automatic solution, but you can import the symbol manually:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config'
```

Answer (score 3):

For Vue projects it is recommended to use the Volar Typscript Plug-in if using VSCode.  After installing Volar follow these steps to get TS working correctly in Vue and Nuxt projects.

1. In your project workspace, bring up the command palette with Ctrl + Shift + P (macOS: Cmd + Shift + P).
2. Type built and select "Extensions: Show Built-in Extensions".
3. Type typescript in the extension search box (do not remove @builtin prefix).
4. Click the little gear icon of "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features", and select "Disable (Workspace)".
5. Reload the workspace. Takeover mode will be enabled when you open a Vue or TS file.

Full details can be found here: [Vue.js Documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode)

Answer (score 1):

After deprecation of Volar, I couldn't make IntelliSense work correctly in Nuxt 3 project, in VSCode for auto imports (if I import manually then it works fine). To solve that, I had to create a `tsconfig.json` file in the root directory of the project with the following content:

```json
{
  "extends": "./.nuxt/tsconfig.json"
}
```

Comment: this is working fine, except when you have a .playground folder... for some reason "extends": "./.playground/.nuxt/tsconfig.json" is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **node_modules** folder and do a clean install

> npm ci

Comment: Could you please explain the reason why this is required, moreover if possible also provide the `command` for doing so.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).